# PyQt SimpleHTTPServer: GUI freezes on starting server

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, multiprocessing, simplehttpserver

I am trying to create a simple desktop app using PyQt that runs a SimpleHTTPServer on clicking a start server button. I have tried using threads(both python threads and Qthread) and understand that this is not possible as it runs into issues with the GIL. Here's the code

```
def btn_startserver_clicked(self):
    server_thread=threading.Thread(target=start_server())
    server_thread.start()


def start_server():
    #to get server's IP
    host=([(s.connect(('8.8.8.8', 80)), s.getsockname()[0], s.close()) for s in [socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)]][0][1])
    start=8000
    end=56999
    PORT = random.randint(start,end)
    print host,":",PORT
    httpd=ThreadedServer(("",PORT), SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
    httpd.handle_request()`
```

I tried creating another process but the same thing happened. Also, if I create another process a new window pops up each time a request is served.

```
def btn_startserver_clicked(self):
    if __name__=='__main__':
        server_process=Process(target=start_server())
        server_process.start()
```

Is there any way around this? I feel using multiprocessing is the right approach but I am new to this and can't figure out why it still freezes.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your examples that lock the GUI is that rather than passing a reference to the function when creating the thread, you are actually running the function immediately and the thread is never created. For example, you should be doing:

```
server_thread=threading.Thread(target=start_server)
```

Note that I drop the brackets on `start_server` otherwise the code waits for `start_server()` to finish executing before creating the `threading.Thread` object, and uses the return value from `start_server()` as the value for the `target` attribute.

A final suggestion, you should really store the created thread as `self.server_thread` to prevent it from being garbage collected.

Comment: Thanks. That was a careless mistake. But how does it still run if python can execute only one thread at a time? Or have i understood this wrong?

Comment: @raksh93 Python switches back and forth between the threads. So multithreading doesn't provide a performance benefit, however it does help keep things like GUIs responsive.

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but this might help you get started:

```
import sys
from urllib.request import urlopen
from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

HOST, PORT = '127.0.0.1', 12345

class HttpDaemon(QtCore.QThread):
    def run(self):
        self._server = HTTPServer((HOST, PORT), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
        self._server.serve_forever()

    def stop(self):
        self._server.shutdown()
        self._server.socket.close()
        self.wait()

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Start', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.httpd = HttpDaemon(self)

    def handleButton(self):
        if self.button.text() == 'Start':
            self.httpd.start()
            self.button.setText('Test')
        else:
            urlopen('http://%s:%s/index.html' % (HOST, PORT))

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.httpd.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to create a simple application for file sharing on a home network